# Java HashMap take out keys based on value

Tags: java, hashmap

This is my Hashmap in which the key is a model `Payment` and value is a `String`, which is an Error occurred during payment.

`Map<Payment, String> mapPaymentWithError = new HashMap<>()`

If there are no errors in Payment we are storing String value as null and the key as Payment model data.

I am trying to group Payment based on whether error `String` was `Null` or `NotNull` from above HashMap which is having many records.

Like below

`List<Payment> withNullErrors = .............. // having String value as Null List<Payment> withErrors = ................... // having String value as NotNull`

How to do this ?

Tried using Collectors.GroupingBy and other ways but its not working

Comment: Could you show the code you have tried please?

Comment: if you need `groupingBy`: `var temp = mapPaymentWithError.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue()==null));` and then `temp.get(true)` and `temp.get(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public class ListFiltering {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Map<Payment, String> mapPaymentWithError = new HashMap<>();
      mapPaymentWithError.put( new Payment( "1" ), "1" );
      mapPaymentWithError.put( new Payment( "null" ), null );
      
      List<Payment> withNullErrors = mapPaymentWithError.entrySet().stream()
              .filter( e ->  e.getValue() == null  )
              .map( e -> e.getKey() )
              .toList();
      
      List<Payment> withErrors  = mapPaymentWithError.entrySet().stream()
              .filter( e ->  e.getValue() != null  )
              .map( e -> e.getKey() )
              .toList();
      
      System.out.println( "with null errors: " + withNullErrors );
      System.out.println( "with other errors: " + withErrors );
   }

   static record Payment( String id ) {}
}
```